# Reducing the spacing in TOC entries for front matter only

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, setspace

I am trying to get 1.5 spacing throughout the document using `setspace` package. However, the spacing in TOC entries for front matter appears more. How to reduce spacing for TOC entries in front matter only.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\frontmatter    
\pagestyle{plain}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalfont Front 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalfont Front 2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalfont Front 3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\normalfont Front 4}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chap 1}
\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection 2}
\chapter{Chap 2}
\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection 2}
\end{document}
```